# Understanding the P2P transfer

Tags: vb.net, p2p

First I need to know about Peer-to-Peer connections. How is the connection made between two computers. Actually I want to make a file sharing application in VB but neither of us has static IP, but the Dynamic.

I'm not asking for some specific code, just some relevant information.